# BLE device does not make new /dev/input/eventX when it reconnects, using Python Gatt Library

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, evdev

I am new to python `gatt` module, and i am having a problem with reconnections.
Basically what I am trying to do is establish a connection with a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device with the python `gatt` module( https://github.com/getsenic/gatt-python ) and then read the input from the `/dev/input/eventX` path with the `evdev` module. I also want to automate the reconnection process, so when the device gets out of range and comes back, it will reconnect and continue working normally.

The problem is that when the device disconnects, and eventually reconnects (via simple routine like this: catch disconnect message -> try to reconnect) if the reconnection has taken more than 2-3 minutes, the connection process does not make a new `/dev/input/eventX` path. This is not happening when the reconnection is successful in between the first 1-2 minutes.

The error I am getting when the 2-3 minutes have passed is:

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in
> **call**
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
> dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
> org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible
> causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the
> message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout
> expired, or the network connection was broken.

The core of the script is the following:

```
def reconnect(mac_address):
    try:
        devices[mac_address].connect()
    except:
        print(f"thread from {mac_address} crashed")

class AnyDevice(gatt.Device):
    shut_down_flag = False


    def connect_succeeded(self):
        super().connect_succeeded()
        print(f"{self.mac_address} Connected")

    def connect_failed(self, error):
        super().connect_failed(error)
        print(f"{self.mac_address} Connection failed.")
        reconnect_thread = threading.Thread(target=reconnect, name=f'reconnect {self.mac_address}',args=(self.mac_address,))
        reconnect_thread.start()

    def disconnect_succeeded(self):
        super().disconnect_succeeded()
        print(f"{self.mac_address} Disconnected")
        if not self.shut_down_flag:
            reconnect_thread = threading.Thread(target=reconnect, name=f'reconnect {self.mac_address}',args=(self.mac_address,))
            reconnect_thread.start()

def gatt_connect_device(mac_address):
    global devices
    devices.update({f'{mac_address}': AnyDevice(mac_address=f'{mac_address}', manager=manager)})
    devices[f'{mac_address}'].connect()


#==== OPEN bd_addresses.txt JSON FILE ====#
if path.exists("bd_addresses.txt"):
    with open("bd_addresses.txt", "r") as mac_addresses_json:
        mac_addresses = json.load(mac_addresses_json)
else:
    print("bd_addresses.txt file NOT FOUND\nPlace it in the same directory as the multiple_scanners.py")
#========================================#



devices={}
manager = gatt.DeviceManager(adapter_name='hci0')

for scanner_number in mac_addresses:
    device_instance_thread=threading.Thread(target=gatt_connect_device, name=f'device instance for {mac_addresses[scanner_number]}', args=(mac_addresses[scanner_number],))
    device_instance_thread.start()
    time.sleep(3)



manager.run()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet of your code, so we can take a look and better help you?

Comment: I did! Btw thank you for editing my post, I will try in the future to be more careful with my syntax to improve posts readability.

Comment: Great, hopefully someone will be able to help. Also, regarding the editing, no problem. This is how stack overflow keeps its very good standards of questions and answers. I encourage you to do the same for posts you see! Good luck